# Deleting previous versions of Windows 10 fails

Tags: windows, windows-10

I am trying to delete `C:\Windows.old`. I tried this: [How to Delete an Old Windows Folder from Windows 10](http://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-delete-the-windows-old-folder-from-windows-10/) but the option isn't listed. Then I tried this: [Delete Your Previous Version of Windows](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/delete-your-previous-version-of-windows), where there is the option to delete the previous versions but it doesn't work. I also tried this: [How to Delete an Old Windows Folder Without Using a Disk](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-files/how-to-delete-cwindowsold-folder-witout-using-disk/8de79467-052f-4ce6-a741-4fa01a168912) using the command line but nothing again (it says access denied at step 5)... any other way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first option you listed will work, you just need to run it as administrator

1. Click `Start`
2. Then type `Disk Cleanup`
3. When `Disk Cleanup` appears right click it and select `Run as Administrator`